# Are edits that convert inline links to markdown links valid?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

An edit that merly converted an inline link to a markdown link valid?

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1382844

The rendered output is the same. All the edit did was make it a markdown link versus an inline link.

Comment: IMO that should have been rejected.

Comment: @bfavaretto and it was...by 2/5 people.

Comment: No, it was approved. It takes 3 same-type votes to reject or approve (on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @bfavaretto I know. I'm pointing to the fact that it was rejected by 2/5 votes, but the 3/5 majority won.

Comment: The user seems to specialise in editing links. However, they *do* seem to take the time to edit other stuff in the posts as well. Mostly. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, they're not. Links on Stack Overflow already automatically get converted to a real link when rendered, so making it actual Markdown serves no purpose whatsoever. The edit should actually make some **visible** change. I don't understand why on Earth people would approve this (though for something like this, a rollback only adds to the clutter).

If it's not a network link that actually gets rendered as a *plain* link, then yes, editing it to use the title of the external page is completely appropriate.

Comment: ...appropriate, along with fixing the *rest* of the post, of course. Not *just* the link. =)