# Should extremely basic edits to perfectly fine posts be approved?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

It seems like a lot more people are beginning to discover the suggested edits functionality. That's awesome. However, it seems like some people are editing just to be editing.

For instance, I saw a perfectly fine answer that had a suggested edit that changed this line

```
Demo here: http://jsbin.com/foobar
```

to this line

```
Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/foobar)
```

I've heard that the "too minor" reason should only used when there are other things that could be improved, but this answer was a text book example of a good answer, aside from using a raw link.

Should an extremely minor edit like this be approved when it doesn't really make the content any better? (in my opinion anyway)

Comment: `it seems like some people are editing just to be editing` Took you a while to notice...

Comment: You're late to the party. We've been complaining about suggested edits and their approval for far longer. :p

Comment: @Bart well, I don't frequent MSO much I guess :P Close as duplicate if appropriate then

Comment: So the original link wasn't clickable? That seems an OK edit to me as it makes visiting said link easier for future readers.

Comment: Short answer: **No**

Comment: @MartinSmith no, it was clickable. It was just a raw link though, like saying http://example.com instead of [this link](http://example.com)

Comment: @Earlz - Ah right. Agree that seems pointless then.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164796/are-edits-that-convert-inline-links-to-markdown-links-valid although that's with links pointing to other stackexchange sites specifically

Comment: Basic rules I apply: if they don't improve anything: reject. If they improve one thing, but do not address all issues: reject. If it's minor, still an improvement and there are no other issues: accept.

Comment: @Bart well, is something like that an "improvement"? It actually provides a bit less information. At least with the raw link you can see the domain and sometimes the URL is half readable. When they convert it to `here` though you have to hover over or click through to figure out what it could be

Comment: I would argue that changing a clickable raw URL to a link with the text "here" (or "click" or "this", etc.) is not an improvement at all.  If they'd changed it to the title of the linked page, that would be different.

Comment: @Earlz In my book that's not an improvement.

Comment: I personally don't take the "well if there are still issues" guideline seriously at all.  If an edit merely formats the code and adds a couple newlines in what would otherwise be an un-formatted ugly block of text, but leaves capitalization and spelling errors. I will approve those all day.

Comment: @SamIam Yes, there's definitely a "don't throw the baby out with the bathwater" line we don't want to cross.  If they make significant improvements, but leave a few typos or capitalization errors, you're right, approve that.  If they opposite is true though, they fix a few typos while leaving the code unformatted, I'd reject the edit.

Comment: @SamIam It's a question of whether they made a good faith attempt to address all issues or not.  If they just formatted the code but clearly never even read any of the rest of the post, then it's too minor.  If the problems elsewhere in the post are not glaring errors that could be conceivably missed in a first pass, then that's fine.

Comment: @SamIam I will certainly improve, though I might simultaneously not approve.

Answer (score 13):

This edit makes the post worse: it replaces a bare URL by the word “here”. Links with descriptive text are better than links with text such as “here” or “this”. A bare URL has the URL itself as a descriptive text, which is not very nice but better than nothing (it at least gives some indication of what kind of content is to be found — an online JavaScript demo, on jsbin.com). Since this edit makes the post worse, I would reject it as “invalid edit” (an edit that makes a post worse is *incorrect*).

If the edit was the other way round, I'd accept it if the post was otherwise perfect, and reject it as “too minor” if there were any other obvious things to fix (formatting, spelling, etc.). “Too minor” is ok as a rejection reason for edits that neither really improve the post nor really worsen it: they're just a waste of time, which is why the “too minor” rejection reason exists.